# Grunt JS file pattern in cwd

Tags: build, gruntjs, cwd

I am using grunt to build my project and have the following src structure:

```
app/src/client/pages/user/users.js
app/src/client/pages/user/users.html

app/src/client/pages/project/projects.js
app/src/client/pages/user/projects.html
```

Now, I am trying to build my project to look like this:

```
app/dist/client/users.html
```

I use the contrib-htmlmin plugin and my grunt config looks like this:

```
htmlmin: {
            options: {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true
            },      
            partials: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: "app/src/client/pages/*/",
                        dest: "app/dist/client/",
                        src: ["*.html"]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

But this is not working at all, no files are being minified.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

As best I can tell, Grunt does not expand patterns in `cwd`, so your option

```
cwd: "app/src/client/pages/*/",
```

never gets converted to an array of matching directories.

You can follow my logic for this conclusion by starting [at this line in the source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/task.js#L132). `grunt.file.expandMapping` ([source here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/file.js#L144)) doesn't call `grunt.file.expand` on your `cwd` pattern.

That doesn't mean you can't do it yourself.  I've used the following pattern to accomplish something similar with `grunt-contrib-sass` when I have sass files spread out over several directories:

```
htmlmin: {
    options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
    },      
    partials: {
        files: grunt.file.expand(['app/src/client/pages/*/']).map(function(cwd) {
            return {
                expand: true,
                cwd: cwd,
                dest: "app/dist/client/",
                src: ["*.html"]
            };
        }),
    }
```

Comment: Why isn't this example on the documentation? It just saved me tons of time.